# Обращение содержания на форму

Tags: лексика

Скажите, как называется способ написания или произнесение слова (выражения),
когда содержание непосредственно выражается формой? Например, напишу сейчас слово **жирным** *наклонным* шрифтом.

Comment: В вашем примере можно назвать выделением.

Comment: По-моему спрашивают, есть ли название для случая, когда слово "наклонный" пишут курсивом, слово "жирный" - жирным (на самом деле полужирным) начертанием, а слово "красный" - красным цветом. Т.е. значение слово "совпадает" со способом отображения.

Comment: *По-моему спрашивают, есть ли название для случая** - я тоже думаю, что именно так. Нужно дать название самому ***подходу, методу*** выражения понятия через использование самого понятия. А у Вас есть идеи относительно ответа?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам не очень критично точное значение термина, то я бы назвал подобное ***идеографическим форматированием***.

Идеограмма - это письменный знак или условное обозночение некоторого понятия (в сравнении, например, с пиктограммой, выражающей только объекты). Есть понятие идеографического письма, т. е. письма, основанного на идеограммах, это, к примеру, отчасти реализуется в древнеегипетской иероглифике. Но у нас слово написано буквами, т. е. назвать письмо идеографическим нельзя.

А вот к форматированию (болд, курсив) тут прямо просится эпитет "идеографическое". Так что если надо не научный термин, а какое-то понятийное выражение, то дарю идею.

Comment: Не точно. Идеограмма - это именно условный знак. А у нас как раз обратное, не обозначение а прямое использование.

Answer (score 0):

В обиходе — жирный (bold), курсив, кегль, размер, разрядка и т. д. — выделение. Типографский текст, созданный или графически отредактированный для особых, акцидентных случаев, соответственно будет акцидентным. Текст «от руки» — каллиграфическим. Его *формальные* возможности в выражении содержания приближаются к изобразительным.

Comment: Не о том вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Одним из *частных случаев* "содержания" является *действие*; по форме оно всегда выражается глаголом. В случае, если сам факт произнесения или написания глагола (**форма**) заключает в себе выраженное им действие (**содержание**), то такое явление называют **перформативностью** (Джон Остин, 1950), а глаголы, которые могут использоваться в таком качестве - *перформативными глаголами* (это, конечно, не относится исключительно к русскому языку). Примеры:

> Приношу свои извинения (извиняюсь), уверяю вас, я вам русским языком
>   говорю, объясняю...

Видимо, можно рапространить данное понятие и на конкретный способ написания:

> Пишу Вам эти строки упрощёнными иероглифами...

Comment: В сети нет даже намека на возможность столь широкого понимая перформативности. Да и вообще, в классическом понимании перформативность - понятие весьма далекое от выражения какого-то единства формы и содержания в отрыве от описания самого перформативного действа. Если бы не это, мне бы такой термин показался бы вполне подходящим...

Comment: Кстати, глагодл писать не обладает перформативным свойством, его как раз и приводят часто для объяснения отличий перформативных гдаголов от прочих.

Comment: Вот немного о перформативности https://books.google.ru/books?id=QVvXBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E&source=bl&ots=sWdGjPq0PL&sig=Fa_s16oxaNb59X1orGruK-JpEC0&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig7-GpoPnKAhXsKJoKHTP1BlEQ6AEISTAI#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E&f=false

Comment: Возможно, сам глагол "пишу" и не относится перформативным, но высказывание в целом (если его суть - продемонстрировать способ написания), наверное, можно отнести к таковым. Сам термин возник именно как "перформативное высказывание" (не "перф. глагол" или "перформативность" вообще) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performativity , а более позднее перенесение "перформативности" на глаголы было связано с особенностями английской грамматики. Считается, что перформативные глаголы не требуют "продолженной" временной формы Present Continuous.

Comment: Например, грамматически возможное выражение 'I'm telling you' избыточно (перформативность глагола позволяет не усложнять его временную форму), и в стилистически безупречной речи оно должно упрощаться до 'I tell you'. В русском языке вряд ли есть подобная потребность классифицировать отдельно глаголы, в то время как "перформативное высказывание" распознаётся по более общему контексту (является или не является в целом высказывание заключённым в нём действием).

Comment: *Возможно, сам глагол "пишу" и не относится перформативным, но высказывание в целом (если его суть - продемонстрировать способ написания)* - ну так бы и писали, что не глагол, а высказывание. Но фокус-то в том, что само понятие перформативности вводится только применительно к глаголам. Т.е. начали пионерничать уже с этого момента, когда обобщили понятие. А смысл?! Высказывание в принципе почти любое в той или иной степени перформативно, если от первого лица и в нем есть перформативный глагол. А вот в отношении "пишу" даже если оно написано иероглифами - большое сомнение.

Comment: *грамматически возможное выражение 'I'm telling you' избыточно* - насколько помню, именно ***грамматически*** невозможно. Впрочем, это вопрос терминологии, а я в принципе отрицаю содержательность терминологических споров. Что это даёт лучше скажите? О чем спор? На что Вы мне возражаете? У меня и тезисов не было достойных полемики.

Comment: Грамматически это возможно:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_I_Am_Telling_You_I'm_Not_Going
фильм: I'm Telling You (Paramount Pictures, 1931)

Comment: У нас разные представления о том, что такое грамматический запрет. ))) А если оное не признать грамматически запрещенным то что запрещает им пользоваться?

Answer (score 0):

Семаформа?
Звучит, конечно, смешно, похоже на семафор. Но смысл сразу понятен - форма, отражающая содержание, значение. С таким понятием - соответствием формы содержанию - часто можно встретится в стихах, например, и вообще в искусстве. Пример - песня Битлов "Here Comes The Sun" - Солнце восходит, здорово, почти физически передает это утреннее ощущение.